# uploading an image to a web server

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So im trying to upload an image with additional information to a web server but im getting errors when im going to upload.

My log cat

> 12-14 00:17:25.246
>   11931-11931/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator
>   D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN 12-14 00:17:25.346
>   11931-11931/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator
>   E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null 12-14 00:17:26.116
>   11931-11931/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator
>   D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN 12-14 00:17:26.256
>   11931-16240/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                                Process: com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator, PID: 11931
>                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator.CreateEvent_2Activity$1UploadImage.doInBackground(CreateEvent_2Activity.java:268)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator.CreateEvent_2Activity$1UploadImage.doInBackground(CreateEvent_2Activity.java:248)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)  12-14 00:17:26.626
>   11931-12007/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9bc0c800
>   (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9df86430 12-14 00:17:26.636
>   11931-11931/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator I/Timeline:
>   Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2322f347
>   time:47950722

MY code

```
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button b_choose;
private Button b_upload;
private Button b_viewimage;
private Button time_button;
private Button date_button;

private ImageView iv_image;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;

private TextView time_textview;
private TextView date_textview;
private TextView timeTextView;
private TextView dateTextView;

String date;
String time;

Intent i = getIntent();
String title;
String address;
String description;
String phone;
String lng;
String lat;
String category;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_event_2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    b_choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_choose);
    b_upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
    /*b_viewimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_viewimage);*/
    /*Date and Time Picker*/
    timeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_textview);
    dateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
    Button timeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.time_button);
    Button dateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date_button);

    iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
    time_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_textview);
    date_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_textview);

    b_choose.setOnClickListener(this);
    b_upload.setOnClickListener(this);




    timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    CreateEvent_2Activity.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    false
            );
            tpd.setThemeDark(true);
            tpd.setTitle("TimePicker Title");
            tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
                }
            });
            tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
        }
    });

    dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    CreateEvent_2Activity.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );
            dpd.setThemeDark(true);

            dpd.showYearPickerFirst(true);

            dpd.setTitle("DatePicker Title");

            dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TimePickerDialog tpd = (TimePickerDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Timepickerdialog");
    DatePickerDialog dpd = (DatePickerDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Datepickerdialog");

    if(tpd != null) tpd.setOnTimeSetListener(this);
    if(dpd != null) dpd.setOnDateSetListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == b_choose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == b_upload){

        Intent i = getIntent();
        title = i.getStringExtra("title");
        address = i.getStringExtra("address");
        time = date_textview.getText().toString();
        date = time_textview.getText().toString();
        phone = i.getStringExtra("phone");
        description = i.getStringExtra("description");
        lng = i.getStringExtra("lng");
        lat = i.getStringExtra("lat");
        category = i.getStringExtra("category");

        uploadImage(title,address,time,date,phone,description,lng,lat,category);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
    String hourString = hourOfDay < 10 ? "0"+hourOfDay : ""+hourOfDay;
    String minuteString = minute < 10 ? "0"+minute : ""+minute;

    String time = hourString+"h"+minuteString+"m";
    timeTextView.setText(time);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    String date = +dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;
    dateTextView.setText(date);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            iv_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(String title, String address, String time, String date, String phone, String description, String lng, String lat, String category) {
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        ServerConnection rh = new ServerConnection();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(CreateEvent_2Activity.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...", true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
            data.put("name", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.title);
            data.put("address", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.description);
            data.put("time", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.time);
            data.put("date", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.date);
            data.put("phone", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.phone);
            data.put("description", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.description);
            data.put("lat", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.lat);
            data.put("lng", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.lng);
            data.put("categoryType", CreateEvent_2Activity.this.category);



            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, data);

            return result;
        }
    }
    UploadImage up = new UploadImage();
    up.execute();

}
```

}

is my code in doInbackground correct?
im new to android programming im still learning how.

Comment: You're not giving the `UploadImage` any parameters so the bitmap array will be empty.

Comment: what do you mean? im sorry, im really new. i dont understand. sorry for my bad english